# Microsoft Office Communicator SDK vs Lync SDK

Tags: c#, lync-2010, office-communicator

Since Lync is the replacement to Microsoft Office Communicator, does that mean that if I write an app that integrates Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 R2, and then later I upgrade to Lync 2010, will I have to rewrite the integration portions of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're talking about client side integration with OCAA or UCCA? These are both still supported against Lync 2010, so your app *should* still work if you upgrade. However, one or both of these APIs will definitely not be supported against the next version of Lync.